# GestureRecognizer taking all Touch Input

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have this Setup in my Storyboard.

[image: Storyboard]

In my first ViewController Scene I have a MapView from MapBox. In there I have put a TextField (AddressTextField). On that TextField when touching the view, i'm running `self.addressTextField.resignFirstResponder()`, but after that neither the mapview, nor any other element in there or in the Embedded Segues react on a touch or click. Probably this is because I didn't completely understand the system of the `First Responder`. I'm thankful for every help.

Edit 1:
I think I know what's going on now, but I don't know how to fix it. When I add the Gesture Recognizer to the `View` (or to the `mapView`, that doesn't matter), the other UIViews and the MapView do not recognize my Tap-Gestures anymore. When I am not adding the Recognizer everything works fine. It seems as if the Gesture Recognizer is recognizing every tap I make on either the `UIViews` or the `MapView` and therefore other gestures are not recognized.

Edit 2: 
I just added a `print()` to `dismissKeyboard()`. As soon as any Touch Event gets recognized on the `MapView` or the other `UIViews`, `dismissKeyboard()` gets called. So I think my thought of Edit 1 was correct. Does anyone know how I can solve this, so that it's not only `dismissKeyboard()` that gets called ?

Some Code:

```
func dismissKeyboard(){
     self.addressTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     dismissKeyboard()
     return true
}

//Class (only partially)
class ViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
     override func viewDidLoad(){
             mapView.delegate = self
             addressTextField.delegate = self
             let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
             self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
     }
}
```

Others are just `@IBAction`s linked to the Buttons, or other elements.

Comment: Can you show some relevant code?

Comment: Is that enough ? The class is about 300 Lines long, that's why I didn't want to add the whole ....

Comment: try return `false` in `textFieldShouldReturn`

Comment: @TungFam `MapView` and `ResultContainerView` are still not responding to any touch actions.

Comment: You've added the tapGestureRecognizer to the view. I can't see your view hierarchy but did you mean to add it to your mapView?

Comment: Updated the question, found the reason for this behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I knew the real issue I was able to solve the problem. I declared a `var keyboardEnabled`. Then I added these lines to my class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var keyboardEnabled = false
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Looks for single tap
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
        self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tap) 
    }

    /* Setting keyboardEnabled */
    //Editing Target did end
    @IBAction func editingTargetDidEnd(_ sender: Any) {
        keyboardEnabled = false
    }

    //Editing TextField Started
    @IBAction func editingAdressBegin(_ sender: Any) {
        keyboardEnabled = true
    }

    //Call this function when the tap is recognized.
    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.mapView.endEditing(true)
        keyboardEnabled = false
    }

    //Implementing the delegate method, so that I can add a statement
    //decide when the gesture should be recognized or not
    //Delegate Method of UITapGestureRecognizer
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        return keyboardEnabled
    }
}
```

With this solution `keyboardEnabled` takes care of deciding wether my `UIGestureRecognizer` should react or not. If the Recognizer doesn't react, the Gesture is simply passed on to the UIViews or other Elements that are in my MapView.

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
func dismissKeyboard(){
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

hope it helps!